# jQuery .detach() vs hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some elements in DOM which I need to show and hide if different events happen. Which is better to use `.detach()` and then `.append()` them again or `.hide()` and then `.show()`. Elements have events attached to them and I'm using jQuery `.on()` for the events. The number of elements which change is not big from a single element to less than 10 elements.

Which is better to use?

Also if an element is not needed in page load but will be needed later should it be created as hidden or should be created when I need it?

Comment: use show/hide. detach() would create another jquery object which would hold the elements html.

Comment: Thanks. What about my other question? (See my updated question.) @DinoMyte

Comment: Have an element hidden. Since dynamically injecting one would impact the performance and would eventually take the markup space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.detach()` and `.append()` functions remove and add elements to the DOM, respectively.

`.show()` and `.hide()` just add the CSS rule `display: none`.

The short answer is that if you are showing / hiding an element *often*, it's better to use `.show()` and `.hide()`, as this action occurs more quickly.

If you need large elements to appear infrequently, it's better to use `.detach()` and `.append()`, as having your DOM be too large can cause your web page to slow down once memory limits start being reached.

Comment: The page has a few elements  its not very large. So I can go with `.show()` and `.hide()` right? What about my other question?

Comment: @rexhin Regardless of whether something is initially shown or initially hidden, apply the same logic. Small things used often use `.show()` and `.hide()`. Large things used infrequently use `.append()` and `.detach()`. It doesn't really matter which you choose for small things used infrequently.